# Probability of a randomly selected word question

Tags: probability

Let $\Sigma = {a, e, f, g, i}.$ Find the probability that a randomly selected 5-letter word will use all three vowels $a, e, i$. Completely stumped on how to proceed. I'm thinking it may be easier if I find all the words that do NOT use any vowels.

Would it be $5$ choose $3$ $*3*3$ / $5^5$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use inclusion/exclusion:

- Take the total number of words, which is $5^5$
- Exclude the number of words that do not contain `a`, which is $4^5$
- Exclude the number of words that do not contain `e`, which is $4^5$
- Exclude the number of words that do not contain `i`, which is $4^5$
- Include the number of words that do not contain `a` or `e`, which is $3^5$
- Include the number of words that do not contain `a` or `i`, which is $3^5$
- Include the number of words that do not contain `e` or `i`, which is $3^5$
- Exclude the number of words that do not contain `a` or `e` or `i`, which is $2^5$

Then, divide the result by the total number of words:

$$\frac{5^5-4^5-4^5-4^5+3^5+3^5+3^5-2^5}{5^5}$$